# Syncing Google Docs with Microsoft Onenote?

Tags: google-docs, automation, synchronization, onenote

Does anyone know a way to sync Google Docs with Microsoft Onenote? If syncing is not possible, then even triggering a backup would be nice.  I know that IFTTT and Zapier can copy from Evernote, but I can't seem to get a new note made on Docs or Onenote to backup on another app.